# Changing axes range in R plot function

Tags: raster, r

I am working with a raster sub-list of raster objects (made up of sea ice concentration values in March and April over a 10 year span from NSIDC) that are projected in polar stereographic. I have cropped the raster list to a management boundary, also projected in polar stereographic, and have plotted the first item in the raster list to test if it was done correctly. Visually, it seems like it works, however I am getting weird values for the axes.

I am wondering why they are not showing up as latitude/longitude values and if there is a way to change them.

```
# Import shapefile
DS_boundary <- readOGR("DS_Management_Shapefile/DS_Management_area.shp")
plot(DS_boundary)

 # Change projection of shapefile to match raster list (i.e. polar stereographic)
proj4string(DS_boundary)
DS_boundary_proj <- spTransform(DS_boundary, crs('+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs'))
proj4string(DS_boundary_proj)

# Crop sub-list to the shapefile
list_mar_apr_crop <- lapply(X=list_mar_apr, FUN=crop, y=DS_boundary_proj)
proj4string(list_mar_apr_crop)

# Test crop
plot(list_mar_apr_crop$`19910301`)
plot(DS_boundary_proj, add=TRUE)
```

[image: Plotting output]

Comment: Also, I should have asked - why did it only crop to a box around the shapefile, rather than following the actual shape of the shapefile?

Comment: Use the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments. To adhere to the polygon boundary  use mask nested in crop.

Comment: Can you explain your comment in more detail? I should have said that I am very new to R.

Comment: The "weird values" are the projected coordinates, in metres (`+units=m`). You can either transform everything to lat-long which will probably stretch it out of all recognition if it is polar, or plot without a box and axes and work out where the (probably curved) lat-long lines are or find a graticule function.

Comment: Spacedman, thank you! That makes sense.